# case insensitive highlighting in php without changing the word itself

Tags: regex, case, case-insensitive

I'm stuck with solving this problem. (I searched for answers here. There are some, but not exactly what I need, that's why I created this question separately. Sorry, if it's a duplicate).

I have the sentence:

> "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but
> the majority have suffered alteration in some form".

Also I have two words, provided in lowercase:

> Word1: lorem
>
> Word2: ipsum

I need to search `$word1` and `$word2` in the sentence `$text`, highlight those words in a given sentence (bake them bold), without changing the case ot the replaced word.

In my example I need  my result to be:

> "... **Lorem** **Ipsum** ... ", but not "... **lorem** **ipsum** ...".

Similarly, for example, if `Word1 = "Lorem"` and that word in provides text is in lowercase, I just want to make that lowercase word in the text bold, without making it capitalized.

I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: I don't see what case has to do with highlighting. What are you doing to bold the word? And it's a simple matter to do case-insensitive searches.

Comment: What language are you using? Why do you need to use regex? Sounds like you can just grab the words you want and replace them with words with bolded text without regex... Most modern languages have a function that can do this...

Comment: Thanks for response.

I'm using PHP and I'm new to it. Don't know how to work with regular expressions.


$text = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.";
$www1 = "lorem";
$www2 = "ipsum";

If I'm doing 
$text = str_ireplace($www1, "<b style='color: #B22222;'>".$www1."</b>", $text);
the result is
"There are many variations of passages of **lorem** Ipsum available.".
However I want it to be "There are many variations of passages of **Lorem** Ipsum available."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ucfirst($str)` first, and then do the string search and convert to bold.

```
$word1 = ucfirst($word1);
$word2 = ucfirst($word2);
```

Or, you can use case insensitive search using stripos($sentence, $word) to get the position of the word, then convert the content from that position to the length of the $word with bold tags/style tags appended

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I see what you are talking about. However, what if in the sentence those words are not capitalized? In this case, after I apply ucfirst("Lorem"), will I be able to search for "lorem" in the text and make it bold **lorem**, not **Lorem** ?

Comment: Or, you can use case insensitive search using stripos($sentence, $word) to get the position of the word, then convert the content from that position to the length of the $word with bold tags/style tags appended